# XAMPP MySQL - Crash when execute AES_ENCRYPT

Tags: mysql, xampp, mariadb

I'm using MySQL(10.4.11-MariaDB) with XAMPP(PHP 7.4.3).

Using phpMyAdmin I try to execute this query: `SELECT AES_ENCRYPT("MyText", "key");`

As a result I get an error: `#2006 - MySQL server has gone away` and in XAMPP `Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.`

In `mysql_error.log` appears nothing about this.

How to fix this?

**UPDATE**

I cleared `mysql_error.log`. Started MySQL, executed query to crash MySQL.

This is content of `mysql_error.log`:

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-03-18 11:37:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-03-18 11:37:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-03-18 11:37:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-03-18 11:37:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-03-18 11:37:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-03-18 11:37:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-03-18 11:37:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-03-18 11:37:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence number 0 in the system tablespace does not match the log sequence number 47116 in the ib_logfiles!
2020-03-18 11:37:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-03-18 11:37:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-03-18 11:37:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-03-18 11:37:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-03-18 11:37:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-03-18 11:37:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-03-18 11:37:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 47116; transaction id 9
2020-03-18 11:37:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-03-18 11:37:55 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-03-18 11:37:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200318 11:37:55
2020-03-18 11:37:55 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce that error - what have you tried to debug it?

Comment: @NicoHaase I want to create a query where I need `AES_ENCRYPT` and before of all, I want to try if function `AES_ENCRYPT` works. So that's how I have got to that query and crash.

Comment: [AES_ENCRYPT function](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/aes_encrypt/) "Encoding with a 128-bit key length is used". Your key string is NOT 128-bit literal. Use, for example, `SELECT AES_ENCRYPT('MyText', UNHEX(MD5('key')));`. PS. The same in answer form was removed, because @NicoHaase decide that you're interested in "why server crashes", not "how to get the result".

Comment: @Akina please don't be unfair - I haven't decided anything for the OP, but your answer did not contain any information that solve the given problem

Comment: @Akina Same thing(crash) with your query

Comment: Test the query listed in User Manual - does it is executed or server crashes too?

Comment: @Akina That `INSERT INTO...`? Same problem.

Comment: Yes. Of course with creating destination table (something like `CREATE TABLE t (txt TEXT);` before). Or `SELECT AES_ENCRYPT('text',SHA2('password',512));` is enough. If this query crashes your server then there is some serious problem with your server instance (or with its relations), not with the query.

Comment: @Akina Just crashing. I'm using last XAMPP with PHP 7.4.3

Comment: A severed leg can't be cured with a pill...

Comment: even on my 12 year old Laptop this runs in 0,1 second with mysql 8.0.19 , so maybe you need another server or try an upgrade to 1.4.12 and if still happens write a bug report to mariadb

Comment: @nbk I don't use a server. I run on my laptop. I also installed MySQL Server Community https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ . And with this one works without a problem. But I prefer to use MySQL with XAMPP.

Comment: You wrote 10.4.11-MariaDB  so you can update Mariadb to 12 and try your luck. mysql 8.0.19 works just fine as i already said.And MAriaDB is not equal to mysql, they share a lot of code, but are seperated for years and have diffrent features.

Comment: @nbk How I can upgrade MariaDB from XAMPP?

Comment: use this https://medium.com/@meness/steps-to-upgrade-mariadb-for-xampp-7924326731d3  this works with every mysql/myariadb version, and remeber to amke the backup as said in the tutorial

Comment: I don't think this is related to `10.4.11-MariaDB` version. I have `10.4.10-MariaDB` to my computer and `SELECT HEX(AES_ENCRYPT("MyText", "key"))` query runs without any problems and it returns `3D80FB9156DE7094FC1E01859E3E52C1`. Check if you have other MySQL or MariaDB servers installed or anything else that is running and using local `3306` port.

Comment: @nbk Done. Now works. MySQL no longer crash. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Works for me! I just installed latest XAMPP (portable) with MariaDB 10.4.11 - `SELECT AES_ENCRYPT("MyText", "key");` works and returns `0x3D80FB9156DE7094FC1E01859E3E52C1`. I guess your installation was corrupted.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I don't know the real reason, but looks like an upgrade to 10.4.12 works perfect now. But if someone still want to find the problem I'm open.